# Ensure text remains visible during webfont load - TypeKit PageSpeed Insights

Tags: seo, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, typekit

I have a website https://www.rosterelf.com/ and Google PageSpeed Insights keeps saying to me

> Ensure text remains visible during webfont load

For this code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/dgp2bhj.css">`

Hence I have researched found out some ways to solve this and hence I updated to below code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/dgp2bhj.css?family=proxima-nova&display=swap">
```

By appending adding, `?family=proxima-nova&display=swap` in above code.

But Google PageSpeed Insights still throwing my the same error.

I have tried few other ways like enabling the cache in `.htaccess` like `ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"` etc .. but this error still exists.

Can someone guide me what should I do here ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just solved that problem, to add the `font-display: swap;` property and remove the lighthouse warning, the file/link exported by Adobe must include that property on its settings, check this [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/using/font-display-settings.html) for reference

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation about something like "?family=proxima-nova&display=swap" working for typekit. If you open up https://use.typekit.net/dgp2bhj.css?family=proxima-nova&display=swap, you'll see the font display is set to auto.

However, you can edit your typekit configuration to set your display to swap, see this article:
https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/user-guide.html/fonts/using/font-display-settings.ug.html

If you do not have controll over the typekit, you can set the display to swap in your local css file:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'proxima-nova';
            src: local('proxima-nova'), url(https://use.typekit.net/dgp2bhj.css);
            font-display: swap;
 }
```

Comment: I have no control as I am calling third party css url. 
I have tried to add a css which you mentioned in your answer in one of local css file which is getting called after my typekit css file. but still issue persists.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/dgp2bhj.css">` this is how i added typekit css .. and then one of my `developer.css` file, i added your provided code but issue still persists.